# Finding bounding boxes of RGB colors in image

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I'm working with a page segmentation algorithm. The output of the code writes an image with the pixels of each zone assigned a unique color. I'd like to process the image to find the bounding boxes of the zones. I need to find all the colors, then find all the pixels of that color, then find their bounding box.

The following is an example image.

[image: Example output image showing colored zones]

I'm currently starting with histograms of the R,G,B channels. The histograms tell me data locations.

```
img = Image.open(imgfilename)
img.load()
r,g,b = img.split()

ra,ga,ba = [ np.asarray(p,dtype="uint8") for p in (r,g,b) ]

rhist,edges = np.histogram(ra,bins=256)
ghist,edges = np.histogram(ga,bins=256)
bhist,edges = np.histogram(ba,bins=256)
print np.nonzero(rhist)
print np.nonzero(ghist)
print np.nonzero(bhist)
```

Output:
(array([  0,   1, 128, 205, 255]),)
(array([  0,  20, 128, 186, 255]),)
(array([  0, 128, 147, 150, 255]),)

I'm a little flummoxed at this point. By visual inspection, I have colors (0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,20,0),(128,128,128),etc. How should I permute the nonzero outputs into pixel values for np.where()?

I'm considering flattening the 3,row,col narray into a 2-D plane of 24-bit packed RGB values (r<<24|g<<16|b) and searching that array. That seems brute force and inelegant. Is there a better way in Numpy to find bounding boxes of a color value?

Comment: So many incredible suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to consider this as a RGB color image, it is simply a visualization of a segmentation that someone else did. You can easily consider it as a grayscale image, and for these specific colors you don't have to do anything else yourself.

```
import sys
import numpy
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('L')

im = numpy.array(img) 
colors = set(numpy.unique(im))
colors.remove(255)

for color in colors:
    py, px = numpy.where(im == color)
    print(px.min(), py.min(), px.max(), py.max())
```

If you cannot rely on `convert('L')` giving unique colors (i.e., you are using other colors beyond the ones in the given image), you can pack your image and obtain the unique colors:

```
...
im = numpy.array(img, dtype=int)

packed = im[:,:,0]<<16 | im[:,:,1]<<8 | im[:,:,2]
colors = set(numpy.unique(packed.ravel()))
colors.remove(255<<16 | 255<<8 | 255)

for color in colors:
    py, px = numpy.where(packed == color)
    print(px.min(), py.min(), px.max(), py.max())
```

I would also recommend removing small connected components before finding the bounding boxes, by the way.

Comment: +1 for the `np.unique`, much better than the histograms. On the rest... he definitely needs to reduce his search space, because each check is very costly. Not sure though that luminance is the way to go, as it may get texts of different colors confused. Probably won't, but it may. I would think it better to divide the whole image by 16 to mix similar colors together.

Comment: @Jaime the image is already segmented, if it wasn't then doing so in RGB would be a very bad thing. The use of luminance is just a "trick" to map the colors chosen to represent the different regions segmented, it certainly can fail with other colors used. In that case, the simplest thing to do is `colors = set(img.getdata())` and pick a label for each item there.

Comment: I'm loathe to convert the RGB to grayscale. I'm doing this for a paper and accuracy is my biggest concern. The 2nd suggestion (the 24-bit packed with unique) works great! I do need more pre-processing on my input images.

Comment: @DavidPoole you don't have a real "RGB" image, as per the initial part of my answer. Whatever that segmentation routine does, it could just as well return the first region with a value of 1, the second with a value 2, and so on. That would be just as "RGB" as your image is. Converting to grayscale works /in the example presented/ because it simply maps the colors you showed in that specific image to /distinct/ values, that is it. If it didn't map to distinct values (i.e., there were at least two colors being mapped to the same gray value), I wouldn't even consider showing it.

Comment: @mmgp The likelihood of a collision in RGB->L is pretty small. But I have 100s of images to test so a zero chance is better (as with the 24-bit solution). I'm not sure how this segmentation code (XYCut) is assigning colors. I have the source so my next step is to modify it to output the zones directly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidPoole I would go with the second piece of code too, if I couldn't modify the segmentation procedure to already give me the regions without the coloring.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Putting all together into a working program, using the image you posted:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import itertools
from PIL import Image

img = np.array(Image.open('test_img.png'))

def bounding_boxes(img) :
    r, g, b = [np.unique(img[..., j]) for j in (0, 1, 2)]
    bounding_boxes = {}
    for r0, g0, b0 in itertools.product(r, g, b) :
        rows, cols = np.where((img[..., 0] == r0) &
                              (img[..., 1] == g0) &
                              (img[..., 2] == b0))
        if len(rows) :
            bounding_boxes[(r0, g0, b0)] = (np.min(rows), np.max(rows),
                                            np.min(cols), np.max(cols))
    return bounding_boxes

In [2]: %timeit bounding_boxes(img)
1 loops, best of 3: 30.3 s per loop

In [3]: bounding_boxes(img)
Out[3]: 
{(0, 0, 255): (3011, 3176, 755, 2546),
 (0, 128, 0): (10, 2612, 0, 561),
 (0, 128, 128): (1929, 1972, 985, 1438),
 (0, 255, 0): (10, 166, 562, 868),
 (0, 255, 255): (2938, 2938, 680, 682),
 (1, 0, 0): (10, 357, 987, 2591),
 (128, 0, 128): (417, 1873, 984, 2496),
 (205, 186, 150): (11, 56, 869, 1752),
 (255, 0, 0): (3214, 3223, 570, 583),
 (255, 20, 147): (2020, 2615, 956, 2371),
 (255, 255, 0): (3007, 3013, 600, 752),
 (255, 255, 255): (0, 3299, 0, 2591)}
```

Not very fast, even with the small number of colors being actually checked...

---

You can find the bounding box for color `r0`, `g0`, `b0` with something along the lines of

```
rows, cols = np.where((ra == r0) & (ga == g0) & (ba == b0))
top, bottom = np.min(rows), np.max(rows)
left, right = np.min(cols), np.max(cols)
```

Rather than iterating through all `2**24` combinations of RGB colors, you can vastly reduce your search space using only the cartesian product of your non-zero histogram bins:

```
for r0, g0, b0 in itertools.product(np.nonzero(rhist),
                                    np.nonzero(ghist),
                                    np.nonzero(bhist)) :
```

You will have non-existing combinations leaking in, that you can filter out checking that `rows` and `cols` are not empty tuples.  But in your example you would have reduced a search space of `2**24`combinations to just 125.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a solution off the top of my head. You can iterate over the pixels in the image from say top-left to bottom-right and save a `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` values for each color. For a given color the `top` value will be the first row you see with this color and the `bottom` will be the last raw, the `left` value will be the minimal column value for pixels in this color and the `right` is the maximal column value you find.

Then, for each color you can draw a rectangle in from `top-left` to `bottom-right` in the desired color.

I don't know if this is qualified as a good bounding box algorithm, but I guess it's ok.